# vim restores cursor position; exclude special files

Tags: vim

The following code is inside my `.vimrc` and generally restores the last cursor position of a file I opened with vim:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
  \ endif
```

I really like this feature and want to leave it turned on, *except for one file*: When commiting with git, vim gets fired up and I can edit the commit message with it. However the commit message file exists before vim starts (and is prefilled), so vim sees it as an existing file and restores the last cursor position (which is usually not where I would like to start to type).

So is there a possibility to modify the above script to exclude the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file?

Comment: :-)  It took me less time to type `ggI` after git commits, actually.

Comment: it's a vim command to go to the beginning of a file and switch to insert mode :-)

Comment: Ah, I see, well it's a start to solve this problem ^^ I'll try that until I can solve this via the script :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading through the manual on auto commands, I noticed that it seems not possible to define the pattern they match to in such a way that they exclude a special pattern. And I also wasn't able to use some variable that contains the current filename, so that I simply expand the existing if to exclude the file.

However, based on the comment by Pavel Shved (about the `gg` moving to the top of the file) I thought that in the same way it should be possible to simply *overwrite* the effect of the position restoring, by simply moving it to the top *later* again. So I came up with this:

```
autocmd BufReadPost COMMIT_EDITMSG
  \ exe "normal! gg"
```

Placing this after the previous `autocmd BufReadPost` simply chains the event execution, so vim, after executing the first and restoring the position, reads this and matches it on the *excluded filename* and uses the `gg` to move the cursor to the top, basically overwriting the effect of the original autocmd.

And that works just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I understand you have already come up with a solution but I had the same question and came up with an alternative that doesn't require chaining.

```
function! PositionCursorFromViminfo()
  if !(bufname("%") =~ '\(COMMIT_EDITMSG\)') && line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
    exe "normal! g`\""
  endif
endfunction
:au BufReadPost * call PositionCursorFromViminfo()
```

Comment: Nice refinement - it seems cleaner than a double-jump!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably investigate mksession.  You can set up VimEnter/VimLeave auto commands to "do the right thing" when you have specified files on the command line (as when git invokes vim).  There are numerous scripts for this floating around, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_multiple_sessions for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its move cursor to last position

> set hidden

Answer (score 0):

Put the following lines instead of your lines in the `.vimrc`:

```
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

Comment: I had to use `silent!` to prevent vim showing an error when opening a file for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to .vimrc worked for me:

```
au FileType gitcommit au! BufEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])
```

(from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Always_start_on_first_line_of_git_commit_message)